# Why is jquery not running on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know why my jquery won't run? I've tried running on button click or page load but it isn't working. Thanks

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:700px;" id="frame" src="bing.com">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("working");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: any error in your browser console? BTW you code have missing `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: You forgot the opening `<body>`. Aside from that it works.

Comment: I do have an open body. DIdn't paste it here

Comment: I just found out that the iframe that's on my page is what's stopping it from working: <iframe style="width:100%;height:700px;" id="frame" src="https://bing.com"> - why does that stop the jquery from working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your `iframe` tag and put in the complete url like this:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe style="width:100%;height:700px;" id="frame" src="http://bing.com"></iframe>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("working");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```